# Fail to apt-get update and Unable to find expected entry of sources. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, kernel, updates, archive

This is what the terminal shows.

```
$ sudo apt-get update

Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                        
Hit:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease              
Hit:5 http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo xenial InRelease
Hit:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease              
Hit:7 https://typora.io/linux ./ InRelease                                     
Hit:8 http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu xenial InRelease                      
Reading package lists... Done
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

The error is:
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial/InRelease  Unable to find expected entry 'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu//source/Sources' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

The website is not found.

I tried  a lot of methods like changing source of update, changing DNS and autoclean the list.They did not work for me. Hope someone can fix my problem.

Thank you very much!

my sources.list:

```
#deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse

deb https://typora.io/linux ./
# deb-src https://typora.io/linux ./
deb http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo xenial main
# deb-src http://realsense-hw-public.s3.amazonaws.com/Debian/apt-repo xenial main
```

Comment: Can you show us your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: @guillermochamorro ok! I just edited the question. Thank you!

Comment: `grep -ri deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/`

Answer (score 0):

Here's the default /etc/apt/sources.list for Ubuntu 16.04:
https://gist.github.com/rohitrawat/60a04e6ebe4a9ec1203eac3a11d4afc1

Check through this file to see where yours is misconfigured. Make sure to run `sudo apt-get update` after you make any changes.

Comment: I copied the default list to replace my old one, but the error is still the same.